# How to get rails to use ajax to update an HTML table row after the db update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table of content with multiple rows.
For any given row I want to be able to verify a record and have that be reflected immediately on the screen by changing the "verify link" hyperlink to be just plain text 'verified'.
Seems like a fairly common pattern for others.

I have the following markup:

```
...# (table stuff).
 = link_to 'verify', verify_link_path(:id => link.id),  class: 'verify', remote: true
```

This (successfully) calls the links controller 'verify_link' method:

```
def verify_link
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  # Ignore additional verify logic for now, just set as verified (when the user clicks verify).
  @link.verified_date = Time.now
  @link.save!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end 
end
```

I know this works... because the database gets updated.

Finally I want to update the page (table-row-cell) to reflect this.
This is where I am stuck.

The controller method successfully calls the following `app/views/links/verify_links.js.erb` file:

```
$(function() {
$(".verify")
  .bind("ajax:success",function(event,data,status,xhr) {
    this.text='verified';
    alert("The link was verified.");
  });
});
```

I know it gets invoked... because I can put `alert("hello world");` at the start and it gets displayed as a pop-up.

The part that isn't working is replacing the 'verify' link with plain text 'verified'.
Actually I can't even the `alert` to work in there at all.
Nothing gets updated in the ui.  On the backend the change in the db is made however, so if I refresh the page I do see the change reflected at that point).

Notes:

- Is there an issue with the fact that there are multiple links? i.e. Should I be using an id, which I would have to munge from the table row id or number
- app version is rails 3.2.17 with the asset pipeline.
- app was originally written in rails 2 and was later upgraded.
- I am using jquery 1.7.2 and rails.js but avoiding frameworks like angular, ember, etc. initially as I want to learn more of the lower level stuff first. Once I do I will then use a framework.

Comment: Looks like you could use a look at angular.js

Comment: Good idea.  In my case I actually I would like to stay away from angular, ember and all the other frameworks initially as I want to learn more of the lower level stuff first.  Once I do I will thenj use a frameowork.  let me update the q

Comment: It looks like you're binding to the ajax:success event in the ajax response itself -- this means that the ajax:success event would have fired before your javascript gets loaded. As a sanity check, see if adding that javascript snippet inline to the page works.

Comment: Even if you don't wish to use Angular or other (client side javascript) frameworks, "three way binding" is what you are looking for. Maybe you should fire a search on these terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@hjing is right. The code inside *app/views/links/verify_links.js.erb* is already a response to your ajax. You need not bind it to the ajax:success.

As you suggested you need to make an id for each link which you'll have to munge from the table row id or number. For example for your your links will look like this:

```
= link_to 'verify', verify_link_path(:id => link.id),  class: 'verify', id: "verify_#{table_row_no}", remote: true
```

then inside your *app/views/links/verify_links.js.erb* you can target that particular link like this:

```
$("#<%= j 'verify_#{table_row_no}' %>").text("verified");
$("#<%= j 'verify_#{table_row_no}' %>").prop("href","#"); #you would also want to change the href in case someone clicks it again
```